# How to type a function which takes interface and translates to another one?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-typescript

I'm trying to make a function (react hook) which wraps StyleSheet.create(), in argument it should take style like object, but with my custom theme values and it should be fully typed with typescript, for example:

```
function useStyle(style){
  const theme = useTheme();
  const newStyle = ...

  // then translate object to StyleSheet.create() type 
  
  return StyleSheet.create(newStyle)
}

const style = {
  container: {
    margin: "small",
    backgroudColor: "background"
  },
  text: {
    color: "text",
    fontSize: "medium"
  }
}

const styleObject = useStyle(style)

// styleObject type should be 
container: {
    margin: number,
    backgroudColor: string
  },
  text: {
    color: string,
    fontSize: number
  }
}
```

So far I'm stuck with my simplified example:

```
type RNViewStyle = {
  margin?: number;
}

type RNTextStyle = {
  fontSize?: number;
}

type ViewStyle = {
  margin?: keyof Theme['spacing'];
}

type TextStyle = {
  fontSize?: keyof Theme['font']['size'];
}

type Style<T> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: ViewStyle | TextStyle;
};

type TranslatedStyle<T> = {
  [Key in keyof T]: RNViewStyle | RNTextStyle
}

type Theme = {
  spacing: {
    small: number;
    medium: number;
    large: number;
  }
  font: {
    size: {
      small: number;
      medium: number;
      large: number;
    }
  }
}

const theme: Theme = {
  spacing: {
    small: 10,
    medium: 20,
    large: 30,
  },
  font: {
    size: {
      small: 10,
      medium: 20,
      large: 30,
    }
  }
}

const translateStyle = <T extends Style<T>>(styles: T): TranslatedStyle<T> => {
  const newStyles: TranslatedStyle<T> = {} as TranslatedStyle<T>;

  for (const key in styles) {
    const style = styles[key];
    const newStyle: RNViewStyle | RNTextStyle = {};

    if (style.margin) {
      newStyle.margin = theme.spacing[style.margin]
    }

    if (style.fontSize) {
      newStyle.fontSize = theme.font.size[style.fontSize]
    }

    newStyles[key] = newStyle;
  }

  return newStyles;
}

const style = translateStyle({
  container: {margin: 'small'},
  text: {fontSize: 'small'}
});
```

I'm getting errors on `style.margin` and `style.fontSize` branches

And this is my React Native example, where `ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle` are my custom valued styles

```
export type FontWeight =
  | '100'
  | '200'
  | '300'
  | '400'
  | '500'
  | '600'
  | '700'
  | '800'
  | '900'
  | 'bold'
  | 'normal';

export type FontTheme = {
  family: string;
  size: {
    small: number;
    medium: number;
    large: number;
    jumbo: number;
  };
  weight: {
    light: FontWeight;
    regular: FontWeight;
    medium: FontWeight;
    bold: FontWeight;
  };
};

export type SpacingTheme = {
  none: number;
  small: number;
  medium: number;
  large: number;
};

export type ColorTheme = {
  background: string;
  foreground: string;
  border: string;
  text: string;
  textInverse: string;
  primary: string;
  secondary: string;
  attention: string; // call to action
  toned: string; // grey
  success: string; // green
  warning: string; // yellow
  error: string; // red
  info: string; // blue
  facebook: string;
  google: string;
  apple: string;
};

export type Theme = {
  isDark: boolean;
  font: FontTheme;
  spacing: SpacingTheme;
  colors: ColorTheme;
};

export type KeyofFontSizeTheme = keyof FontTheme['size'];

export type KeyofFontWeightTheme = keyof FontTheme['weight'];

export type KeyofSpacingTheme = keyof SpacingTheme;

export type KeyofColorTheme = keyof ColorTheme;

// Style Types

export type ViewStyle = SpacingStyle &
  AlignmentStyle &
  FlexStyle &
  BorderStyle &
  DimensionStyle &
  PositionStyle &
  BackgroundStyle;

export type ImageStyle = {};

export type TextStyle = AlignmentStyle &
  SpacingStyle & {
    fontSize?: KeyofFontSizeTheme;
    fontWeight?: KeyofFontWeightTheme;
    fontColor?: KeyofColorTheme;
    textAlign?: 'left' | 'right' | 'center' | 'justify';
  };

export type MarginStyle = {
  margin?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
  marginVertical?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
  marginHorizontal?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
  marginTop?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
  marginRight?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
  marginBottom?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
  marginLeft?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
};

export type PaddingStyle = {
  padding?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
  paddingVertical?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
  paddingHorizontal?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
  paddingTop?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
  paddingRight?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
  paddingBottom?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
  paddingLeft?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
};

export type SpacingStyle = MarginStyle & PaddingStyle;

export type AlignmentStyle = {
  align?: 'center' | 'start' | 'end';
};

export type FlexStyle = {
  flex?: boolean | number;
  direction?: 'row' | 'column' | 'row-reverse' | 'column-reverse';
  wrap?: 'wrap' | 'nowrap' | 'wrap-reverse';
  justify?:
    | 'center'
    | 'start'
    | 'end'
    | 'space-between'
    | 'space-around'
    | 'space-evenly';
  overflow?: 'visible' | 'hidden' | 'scroll';
  gap?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
  rowGap?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
  columnGap?: KeyofSpacingTheme;
};

export type BorderStyle = {
  borderColor?: KeyofColorTheme;
  borderWidth?: number;
  borderTopWidth?: number;
  borderRightWidth?: number;
  borderBottomWidth?: number;
  borderLeftWidth?: number;
  borderRadius?: number;
};

export type DimensionStyle = {
  width?: number | `${number}%`;
  minWidth?: number | `${number}%`;
  maxWidth?: number | `${number}%`;
  height?: number | `${number}%`;
  minHeight?: number | `${number}%`;
  maxHeight?: number | `${number}%`;
};

export type PositionStyle = {
  position?: 'absolute' | 'relative';
  top?: number;
  right?: number;
  bottom?: number;
  left?: number;
};

export type BackgroundStyle = {
  backgroundColor?: KeyofColorTheme;
};


import NamedStyles = StyleSheet.NamedStyles;

export type Styles<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle;
};

export function useStyles<T extends Styles<T>>(styles: T): NamedStyles<T> {
  const theme = useTheme();

  return useMemo(() => {
    const returnStyles: NamedStyles<T> = {} as NamedStyles<T>;

    // Translate styles to valid react native style objects

    return StyleSheet.create(returnStyles);
  }, [styles, theme]);
}
```

Comment: Are `ViewStyle` and `TextStyle` supposed to be mutually exclusive?  Or can something be both at the same time?  If they don't have to be mutually exclusive I'd do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wk3yJW).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: They have to be mutually exclusive because StyleSheet.create() takes React Native 

``type NamedStyles<T> = {[P in keyof T]: ViewStyle | TextStyle | ImageStyle};``

Comment: A union is not exclusive in TypeScript, so they don't *have* to be mutually exclusive.  That's why I'm asking.  A mutually exclusive union would look more like `{ margin: number, fontSize?: never} | { margin?: never, fontSize: number}`.  Also you wrote `if (style.margin) { }  if (style.fontSize) { }` instead of  `if (style.margin) { } else if (style.fontSize) { }` so your code seems to think they might not be exclusive either.  Can you [edit] to clarify (e.g., use `else` if they are exclusive)?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand because english isn't my native language, but the main idea is that for example [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet) in first example type of ``container`` is ViewStyle and ``title`` is TextStyle because different components take different ``style`` props, and I'm trying to create a function thats translates my object with values relative to my custom theme to absolute values and at the same time do the same translation with types

Answer (score 0):

In my project I was trying to enforce types too. Then after realising that I created a huge boilerplate only for myself, I decided to relax requirements and go for an easier solution. I know that this is not a perfect answer, but at least I can share you some experience.

I created this:

```
function createSize(size: number): WidthHeight {
  return { width: size, height: size };
}

export const AppDimensions {
  Icon: {
    small: createSize(14)
    big: createSize(17)
    ...
  },
  Thickness: {
    thin: 1
  },
  Radius: {
    small: 16,
    big: 64
    ...
  },
  Font: {
    tiny: 14,
    normal: 17,
    ...
  }
}
```

Instead of relying on pre-made components like `<Text />` or `<Button />` I made my own "branded" components like `<ButtonPrimary />`, `<Title />`, `<Subtitle />`, `<Text />`, ` and then used inside them all the defined styles in AppDimensions.

So for example, my `<SubTitle />` component would be:

```
<Text style={{ fontSize: AppDimensions.Font.big }}>{text}</Text>
```

I'm not enforcing the style: I'm just indicating the "right path" to use my custom components that are already styled. This makes the code cleaner to read (`Subtitle` is better than `Text with size = 20`) and you don't have to thing about the right typing: just the right use of it and the correct components to have.

Need a special button? Create the `<ButtonSpecial />` and reuse it, but remember to use the AppDimension thing!

If for any reason you need to use dimensions for example for margins, programmers will know that inside `AppDimensions.Margin.*` they will find the exact value they need, maintaining your view spacing always the same. And if something will go in the "wrong" direction *(example hot-fixes, a component that needs to be very custom or other things...)* you can still apply for your classical `style` value with any number, instead of trying to ignore your enforced typings.

This is also a way to get all the cases when your values were "non-standard", aka magic numbers or margins/paddings with some magical stuff in there *(Views with padding 12 then 17 then 22)*.

---

If you still want to go with your path, I suggest you to simplify the objects into small types and define immediately the values that your style needs to have.

```
const Fonts = {
  small: 12,
  medium: 14,
  large: 16,
  huge: 20,
};
type FontSize = keyof typeof Fonts;

// Example of usage
function fontSizeToNumber(fontSize: FontSize) {
  return Fonts[fontSize];
}
```

Only then try to compose them into bigger types, so you have the right granularity to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I'm doing similar thing but my theme is dynamic value retrieved from react context that could change, I don't know if your method would work in my case

Comment: You can check my code [here](https://github.com/michalfedyna/organization-app/blob/development/src/components/Layout/Container/Container.tsx) for example

Comment: Ah, ok, I understand. If your GUI choices are somehow guided, like with a `<Select />` where you can select one of your 4 font sizes, it could still work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to refactor my hook:

```
const styles = useStyles(theme => ({
container: {
  ...getAlign(style),
  ...getBackground(style, theme.colors),
  ...getBorder(style, theme.colors),
  ...getSize(style),
  ...getSpacing(style, theme.spacing),
  ...getView(style, theme.spacing),
},
}));
```

To:

```
const styles = useStyles({
container: {
  align: 'center',
  background: 'background',
  border: 'none',
  padding: 'medium',
  margin: 'large',
}});
```